# How to dynamically add rows in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I would like to dynamically add rows in my Google Sheet, depending on the value of cell B12. For each row, I would like to write "Arrangement 1", "Arrangement 2" and so on, in every first column (A), until I reach the number in B12. On the 2nd column (B), next to each "Arrangement" (starting on row 15), I would like to select a value that is among others on other sheet (Sheet2), taken from a Google Form.

For now I have this code but I'm still quite far from what I want:

```
function addRows() {

// Opens SS by its ID

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("162JykMqxPnj9j3-
DVbG0UYbHgVRz2FtOWgDEarJ8kr8");

// Get the name of this SS

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // or whatever is the name of the sheet 
var range = sheet.getRange(12,2); 
var data = range.getValue();

var range2=sheet.getRange(15,1);


for(var i=0;i=data;i++) {
sheet.insertRowAfter(range2)


}

}
```

Can somebody please help me? I can't even find the exact tag for this .gs but I guess its like JS..

Comment: Hey Buddy :3 i am trying to help, but i need more details, because i don‘t get your question at all :/ 1. When should this function/event happen? 2. can you Share some sort of example sheet? (with Description like „if this..then this..“

Comment: Ahah np, thank you for helping! I'm using Form Publisher, which is an add-on in Google Spreadsheets. It basically lets you work with Google Forms and Google Sheets: you can save and print the answers from the form into a sheet. This should happen when the form that is working with this spreadsheet is answered. If in the form the answer to "Arrangements" was "3", in the sheet should be created 3 rows: "Arrangement 1", "Arrangement 2", "Arrangement 3"

Comment: And next to each "Arrangement", write a value that is already in "Sheet2"